# HKTextview emoji detection

Tags: ios, uitextview, emoji

I'm having an issue. I am using the [Hakawai framework](https://github.com/linkedin/Hakawai) in an app so that I can have mention support (@username).

The issue I've run into is that the textfield I am using is not registering the case where there is no text and a user types an emoji into the textview. As we are using `HKWTextView`, I believe the `textViewShouldChangeTextInRange` delegate method is never called, even if implemented. The only replacement I can think to use is :

```
- (void)textView:(HKWTextView *)textView didChangeAttributedTextTo:(NSAttributedString *)newText
    originalText:(NSAttributedString *)originalText
   originalRange:(NSRange)originalRange;
```

in `HKWTextView`, but that's still not picking up on emojis being typed in when no other text has.

The functionality I would like is:
- Text view is empty
- user types in anything, emoji included
- textview width shortens, "Post" button appears.

Right now, typing emojis into the empty text view will not make the post button appear. However, it's worth mentioning that once the emojis are typed in, if there is more than one, deleting one of them WILL make the post button appear. I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. @richiereitz were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Nikant yes! It turns out that HKWTextView does some rewiring of the'UITextView delegate methods that are fired. Try handling the input in the UITextView delegate method textViewDidChangeSelection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this -  It turns out that HKWTextView does some rewiring of the UITextView delegate methods that are fired. Try handling the input in the UITextView delegate method textViewDidChangeSelection. That method will be fired when an emoji is typed.